# Scala Compare two delimited strings and generate a third delimited string

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two strings `str1=A#2021-04-02,B#2021-04-01,C#2021-04-02` and `str2=A#2021-04-02#60.0,B#2021-04-02#80.0,C#2021-04-01#60.0`.

The first part of the string is `group` and the second part is `date`. `str2` will have an additional field percentage. Now I want to generate a string by comparing the two strings like if the group part matches then check if the date part of the `str2` is greater than the date part of the `str1` and the `percentage` part of str2 should be `>= 75`.

The output string should be like `str3=A#2021-04-02,B#2021-04-02,C#2021-04-02` since for group B `str2` has greater date than `str1` and `percentage >= 75`.

If `str1=A#2021-04-02,B#2021-04-01,C#2021-04-02` and `str2A#2021-04-02#60.0,B#2021-04-02#60.0,C#2021-04-01#60.0` then `str3` will be `A#2021-04-02,B#2021-04-01,C#2021-04-02` since the percentage part is not >= 75.

Comment: Is it related to spark or just comparing values in scala

Comment: And also do you need to check only group B or all group? if so what is the precedence ?

Comment: Just use a regex and pattern matching. I guess is the simplest way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```scala
def parseString(s: String) = s.split(',').map(_.split('#'))

val str1: String = ???
val str2: String = ???
    
//Note:
// 1. collect would drop invalid parsed string silently
// 2. we are not parsing date and leaving it as string for simplicity - i.e. we assume all dates are valid string
// 3. `p.toDouble` can fail if p is not a valid double
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(parseString(str1)).collect { case Array(g, d, _*) => g -> d }
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(parseString(str2)).collect { case Array(g, d, p, _*) => g -> (d, p.toDouble) }

// 3. we assume a left outer join here base on your requirement to default to the left date if condition fail
val str3 = rdd1.leftOuterJoin(rdd2).map {
  case (g, (d1, Some((d2, p)))) if d2 > d1 && p >= 75 => s"$g#$d2"
  case (g, (d1, _)) => s"$g#$d1"
}.collect.mkString(",")
```

Comment: How can I make sure the rdds join will keep the input string sequence. I want the output also in the same sequence of A, B, C, D instead of any other order.

Comment: As in "A#...B#...C#..." and not "B#...A#...C#"? Current order should depends on `rdd1`'s order. You can do a `sortByKey` on `rdd1` or after joining like `rdd1.leftOuterJoin(rdd2).sortByKey().map { ... } ...`